# How to setup redis cache for moodle sever?

Tags: moodle

I was trying to setup redis cache for moodle server. My moodle serve is very slow. So I installed redis server to change the cache from file cache to redis. But when I open moodle server and try to configure redis cache, I am not getting the option of add instance for redis. Can someone guide me how to configure redis server to enable redis cache for moodle server ??

Comment: Note: I installed moodle server in my ubuntu using lampp server

Answer (score 2):

There is official docs at https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Redis_cache_store that explains the rquired steps.

Make sure that you have installed `Redis php driver` and the green tick mark is visible as the doc states  `When installed, you should see a tick next to "Redis" under "Installed cache stores" and a link to add an instance.`

Comment: The problem with those official docs on the docs.moodle.org site is that they don't explain what you have to do IN REDIS to get the Redis cache working. It only explains what you need to do IN MOODLE to connect Moodle to Redis.

Comment: @luisdev, official docs on the docs.moodle.org site have a valid reason not to do so. Infact it applies even in many other apps docs. The reason is, moodle and redis are two different app from different developers, therefore you will not find redis docs in moodle site neither will you find moodle docs in redis site. However moodle should atleast point to a redis doc site a working example.